# Optimising data-structures so that they take advantage of virtual memory

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, caching, memory-management

I would like to know how to optimise data-structures in openCV (the mat type specifically) so that I am able to leverage the operating systems built in memory/virtual memory management.

For a full context please read the Q and A [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315951/caching-in-3d-data-structures-and-octree-recursion-hrrm/315955?noredirect=1#comment668879_315955) - but otherwise the situation could be summed up that I have a large collection of mats<sup>*</sup> that I'll need to access *arbitrarily* and *rapidly*. The main complication is that full amount of data is well above the amount of RAM available.

<sup><sub>(*Conceptually the data is a recursively defined 3D array of 3D arrays, but let's not muddy the water with that confusion!)</sub></sup>

Rather than build my own LRU cache and RAM-hungry and inefficient 'page' addressing strategies to access it, I'd rather let the OS do this for me.

I think I get the concepts, but when it comes to the actual implementation I'm twiddling thumbs:

- Is this a generic C++ consideration, or something I need to address at the openCV level?
- Is it as simple as making the granularity of the of data close to (but not over) 4KB? (see the solution [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315951/caching-in-3d-data-structures-and-octree-recursion-hrrm/315955?noredirect=1#comment668879_315955) for the 4KB motivation)
- How would the mat(s) actually be saved, accessed and represented on disk? (is this how [memory-mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) is involved?)

Comment: If you can manage access patterns, like reading 1 mb of linear address space from start to finish, the OS will be very good at predicting what you will want to read next, and read it for you ahead.  But really, past a certain point, you'll be limited by disk io (unless you are using crazy fast hard storage); so your goal at that limit is to avoid reading stuff more than once (well, to stop reading it after a bit to avoid thrashing).  Basically, try to push back against arbitrary.  Any improvements there may dominate anything else you can do.

Comment: @Yakk, 'avoid reading stuff more than once': that's what a LRU/LFU cache works to manage - as I understand it that kind of functionality is implied in the algorithms behind memory management.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a generic C++ consideration, or something I need to address at the openCV level?

You just allocate and use boatloads of memory.  **The whole point of paging / virtual memory is that it's completely transparent**.  Everything gets *extremely* slow, but keeps working.  You don't get `ENOMEM` until you're out of swap space + RAM.

On a normal Linux system, your normal swap partition should be very small (under 1GB), so you'll probably need to `dd` a swap file, and `mkswap` / `swapon` on it.  Make sure the swap file is has read-write permission for root only.  Obviously every major OS will have its own procedures.

> Is it as simple as making the granularity of the of data close to (but not over) 4KB? (see the solution here for the 4KB motivation)

If you have pointers to other data, make sure you keep them together.  You want all the small "hot" data to be in only a few pages that a decent OS LRU algorithm won't page out.

If you have hot data mixed with cold data, it will easily get paged out and lead to an extra page-file round trip before the cache miss for the final data can even happen.

Like Yakk says, sequential access patterns will do much better, because disk I/O does better with multi-block reads.  (Even SSDs have better throughput with larger blocks).  This also allows prefetching, which allows one I/O request to start before the previous one's data arrives.  Maxing out I/O throughput requires pipelining requests.

Try to design your algorithms to do sequential accesses when possible.  This is advantageous at all levels of memory, from paging all the way up to L1 cache.  Sequential access even enables auto-vectorization with vector-registers.

[Cache blocking (aka loop tiling)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling) techniques are also applicable to page misses.  Google for details, but the main idea is to do all the steps of your algorithm over a subset of the data, instead of touching *all* the data at each step.  Then each piece of data only has to be loaded into cache once total, instead of once for each step of your algorithm.

Think of DRAM as a cache for your giant virtual address space.

---

> How would the mat(s) actually be saved, accessed and represented on disk? (is this how memory-mapping is involved?)

[Swap space / the pagefile is the backing store for your process's address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).  So yes, it's very similar to what you'd get if you allocated memory by [`mmap`ing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) a big file instead of making an anonymous allocation.